# How to compare multiple dates in a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am wondering how am I able to compare dates in a list. I would like to extract the "earliest" date. 
(I did a for loop as I had to replace some characters with '-')

```
comment_list = comment_container.findAll("div", {"class" : "comment-date"})
D =[]

  for commentDate in comment_list:
    year, month, day = map(int, commentDate.split('-'))
    date_object = datetime(year, month, day)
    date_object = datetime.strptime(commentDate, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')   
    D.append(date_object)

print(D)
```

Output:

```
['2018-06-26', '2018-04-01', '2018-07-19', '2018-04-23', '2018-08-25', '2018-06-08', '2018-06-14', '2018-07-08', '2019-03-15', '2019-03-15', '2019-03-15', '2019-03-15', '2019-03-15']
```

I want to extract the earliest date:

Eg.

> '2018-04-01'

Comment: I’m typing this on my phone so can’t test it, but should be something like 'D.sort()[0]' to sort and get first element. Or even easier, just use max or min

Comment: Your loop seems totally pointless, by the way. You extract the integer parts from the string, then build a new date, then ignore that and build another new date that you immediately turn back into the same string it was parsed from.

Comment: If the dates are strings in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, just `min(comment_list)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the min function:

```
A = ['2018-06-26', '2018-04-01', '2018-07-19', '2018-04-23', '2018-08-25', '2018-06-08', '2018-06-14', '2018-07-08', '2019-03-15', '2019-03-15', '2019-03-15', '2019-03-15', '2019-03-15']
print(min(A))
```

produces

```
2018-04-01
```

Answer (score 1):

```
comment_list = comment_container.findAll("div", {"class" : "comment-date"})
D =[]

  for commentDate in comment_list:
    year, month, day = map(int, commentDate.split('-'))
    date_object = datetime(year, month, day)  
    D.append(date_object)

print(min(D))
```

You should keep the dates as datetime objects and then use the `min()` builtin function to determine the earliest date

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime 

D = ['2018-06-26', '2018-04-01', '2018-07-19', '2018-04-23', '2018-08-25', '2018-06-08',
 '2018-06-14', '2018-07-08', '2019-03-15', '2019-03-15', '2019-03-15', '2019-03-15', '2019-03-15']
D.sort()
print(D[0])
```

or this if you dont want change D

```
T = D[:]
T.sort()
print(T[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Siong you can use `min(D)`. You can achieve the same like this:

```
comment_list = comment_container.findAll("div", {"class" : "comment-date"})
D = [datetime.strptime(commentDate, '%Y-%m-%d') for commentDate in comment_list]

print(min(D))
```

Working with `datetime.datetime` objects is usually preferable since the comparisons you make are not based on the formatting of the string. You can always convert to string later on:

```
min_date_str = min(D).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that all dates are correctly padded with zeros (i.e. `01` for January not `1` and so on) then simple `min` or `max` will be enough. However I want to note that `tuple`s of `int`s might be also sorted which might be of use if you encounter mixed padded and not padded dates, consider for example:

```
d = ['2018-7-1','2018-08-01']
print(min(d)) #prints 2018-08-01 i.e. later date
print(min(d,key=lambda x:tuple(int(i) for i in x.split('-')))) #prints 2018-7-1
```

This solution assumes data are not broken, i.e. all elements produced by `.split('-')` might be turned into `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

d = ['2018-7-1','2018-08-01']

date_mapping = dict((parse(x), x) for x in d)
earliest_date = date_mapping[min(date_mapping)]
print(earliest_date)

>>>> '2018-7-1'
```